# SecondsConverter.java:19: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int

Tags: java

I have to do a program for textbook exercises. The intended purpose is to input a number for seconds, and convert it to days, hours, minutes, and seconds.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;

    public class SecondsConverter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.print("Enter a number for seconds :: ");
       int input = keyboard.nextInt();

       int days = input/86400;
       int hours = (input%86400)/3600;
       int minutes = ((input%86400)/3600)/60;
       int seconds = ((input%86400)/3600)%60;

       System.out.println(days = " days, " + +hours + " hours, " + +minutes + " minutes, and " + +seconds + " seconds");

     }
}
```

Here is the full error:

```
----jGRASP exec: javac -g SecondsConverter.java

SecondsConverter.java:19: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int
System.out.println(days = " days, " + +hours + " hours, " + +minutes + " minutes, and " + +seconds + " seconds");
                                                                                                   ^
1 error

----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

Comment: What is `days = " days, "`? Why is `days =` just sitting there?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your specific issue it is a result of incorrect syntax in your `System.out.println()` call.

You have too many plus operators and you're using equals as well. You want something like this:

```
System.out.println(days + " days, " +hours + " hours, " +minutes + " minutes, and " +seconds + " seconds");
```

As a side note your code doesn't work when the user enters a value of 60, it prints "0 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes, and 0 seconds"

Also, you never close the `Scanner` either. Make sure you call `keyboard.close();` when you're finished with it.

**EDIT:** 
The following items are more code review and general enhancements that I thought of which might help you with this and other programming efforts. Due to the simplicity of this program I thought it might be a good opportunity to illustrate a few important principles.

First, consider how you're going to test your code when you're designing it. I would suggest you separate your business logic (the part that calculates your results) into a separate method. This will allow you to invoke the method and pass automated inputs to it rather than having to type in values manually to test it.  Here is an example with the business logic removed:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.print("Enter a number for seconds :: ");
   int input = keyboard.nextInt();

   if(input < 0){
       System.out.println("Sorry, negative values are not valid.");
   }else{
       SecondConversionResult result = calculate(input);

       System.out.println(result.getDays() + " days, " +result.getHours() + " hours, " +result.getMinutes() + " minutes, and " +result.getSeconds() + " seconds");
   }
 }

/**
 * Calculates the number of days, hours, minutes, and seconds represented by the specified number of seconds.
 * For example 3600 seconds is 1 hour.
 * @param input the number of seconds to convert to days, hours, minutes, and seconds 
 * @return an object representing the result of converting a number of seconds to number of days, hours, minutes, and seconds 
 */
public static SecondConversionResult calculate(int input){
    int seconds = ...
    int minutes = ...
    int hours = ...
    int days = ...

    return new SecondConversionResult(seconds, minutes, hours, days);
}
```

You will notice that this new method, which I have simply called `calculate` takes an integer input and produces an object that represents the results. This object is an instance of `SecondConversionResult` which is a simple class I created to hold the results of the conversion. This class is shown below:

```
public class SecondConversionResult {
    private int seconds, minutes, hours, days;

    public SecondConversionResult(int sec, int min, int hrs, int days){
        seconds = sec;
        minutes = min;
        hours = hrs;
        this.days = days;
    }

    public int getSeconds() {
        return seconds;
    }

    public int getMinutes() {
        return minutes;
    }

    public int getHours() {
        return hours;
    }

    public int getDays() {
        return days;
    }
}
```

Note: In most cases I would create setter methods for a class like this one, but due to the simplicity of what we're doing here I don't think it's really necessary.

You're probably wondering what all of this allows us to do. Well, now that we have a separate method that we can pass an input and obtain a result from we can write some very simple JUnit tests to ensure that our code works as expected. If you're not familiar with JUnit you can read the [Getting Started Guide](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Getting-started).

For example we can write very specific tests like this:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class JUnitTests {
    @Test
    public void test0() {
        SecondConversionResult result = Main.calculate(0);
        assertEquals(0, result.getDays());
        assertEquals(0, result.getHours());
        assertEquals(0, result.getMinutes());
        assertEquals(0, result.getSeconds());
    }
...
```

or we can write a very generic test like the one that follows which tests all values from zero seconds up to 10 days (864000 seconds):

```
@Test
public void testAllUpTo10Days() {
    for(int days = 0; days < 10; days++){
        for(int hours = 0; hours < 24; hours++){
            for(int min = 0; min < 60; min++){
                for(int sec = 0; sec < 60; sec++){
                    int input = sec + min*60 + hours*60*60 + days*24*60*60;
                    System.out.println("Testing input of "+input);
                    SecondConversionResult result = Main.calculate(input);
                    assertEquals(days, result.getDays());
                    assertEquals(hours, result.getHours());
                    assertEquals(min, result.getMinutes());
                    assertEquals(sec, result.getSeconds());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now we have a very simple way to ensure that our solution works for whatever scenarios we need it to. I hope this helps you both now and in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try `System.out.println(days + " days, " + hours + " hours, " + minutes + " minutes, and " + seconds + " seconds");`. Issue is with your concatenation from what i can see.

Answer (score 0):

The formatting of your `System.out.println` is wrong

try

```
System.out.printf ("days = %d, hours = %d, minutes = %d, seconds = %d", 
                                                  days, hours, minutes, seconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your System.out.println, you put an equal sign instead of a plus sign, and multiple other syntax errors.

```
System.out.println(days **=** " days, " + +hours + " hours, " + +minutes + " minutes, and " + +seconds + " seconds");
```

should be

```
System.out.println(days + " days, " + hours + " hours, " + minutes + " minutes, and " + seconds + " seconds");
```